# Regex for http:// but not https://

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to flag a textarea that contains a URL starting with `http://`, but not with `https://`. I thought this should work, but I'm getting the alert even when all URLs are `https`.

```
$('#template_form').submit(function() {
    alert("this is the text: " + $("#template_data").val() );
    val = $("#template_data").val();
    if (val.search(/^http:\/\//)){
        alert("there's a URL in there...");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});

<textarea id="template_data">This is a test of the new URL validation. Let's add a link to https://www.test.com</textarea>
```

This *should* only present the second alert if the URL were `http://www.test.com`, but it's throwing it even as is, with `https://`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why can't you just try with \http:\g  ?

Comment: `search` returns -1 for no match, which evaluates to true.

Comment: If you want a boolean use `regexp.test(string)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for `search()`:

> A String method that tests for a match in a string. It returns the index of the match, or -1 if the search fails.

`-1` will make the if statement evaluate to true (`if (-1) {alert("true");}`. So either switch to `match()` or `test()`, or check for `if (val.search(...) > -1)`

Also the `^` is wrong in your regex, it would only match from the start of the string.

```js
$('#template_form').submit(function() {
  alert("this is the text: " + $("#template_data").val());
  val = $("#template_data").val();
  if (val.match(/http:\/\//)) {
    alert("there's a URL in there...");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="template_form">
  <textarea id="template_data">This is a test of the new URL validation. Let's add a link to https://www.test.com</textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

[String.search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) is not boolean:

> **Return value**
>   The index of the first match between the regular expression and the given string; if not found, -1.

Further in that same piece of documentation:

> When you want to know whether a pattern is found and also its index in
>   a string use `search()` (**if you only want to know it exists, use the
>   similar [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method, which returns a boolean**)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#template_form').submit(function() {
  if ($("#template_data").val().indexOf("http:\/\/") > -1) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});
```

Here is another way.